# Loading part of HTML from another file using JQuery in JSP page gives 404 Not Found error

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, jsp

I have used JQuery to load the small part of my JSP page but I am getting **404 Not Found error**. I have placed the **home.jsp** with **sample.jsp**. I have written a html form in **sample.jsp** file and have loaded the same file to a div in **home.jsp** using **load()** method of JQuery.

---

***home.jsp***

```
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#app" ).load( "templates/form-signin.html" );
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Probably you are executing your script by clicking it. try to call it via a web server using localhost or something similar

Comment: Thank you for your response, and I have not executed script by clicking. It will execute after the page gets loaded. And yes, I am using **Tomcat Server** for serving my **JSP** page.

Comment: try to find your error in browsers debugger.. or check whether ur html location is proper or not...

Answer (score 1):

Check the URL which gives you 404 in the network tab of your browser's developer options. Then check if you can open it manually. You'll probably get a 404 this way too. Make sure the file is accessible on that URL and adjust the location/server settings/url accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I already have tired that. I have opened that link manually from the network tab of my browser and got same error. The file is in the same location. i.e. inside **views/templates** folder. But I have tried with only **views** folder too but got the same error.

Comment: Then the problem is not with your javascript but rather with your web server configuration. Also, check for any typos in the filename or in the url (note that on UNIX-based systems the filenames and therefore the URLs are case-sensitive in most cases).

You could also check if you can access the form from your browser. If you are viewing your jsp as `http://asd/home.jsp`, then you should be access the form as `http://asd/templates/form-signin.html`. If not, please make sure that the html file is placed in a folder called `templates` within the same folder as the jsp file.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I solved it. Instead of a JQuery load() call, I have created an API that serve that sample.jsp file with a HTML form inside the div of home.jsp.

---

***home.jsp***

```
<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( "#app" ).empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/appname/loginform",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#app").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

Now the above API call with return that form and it will display inside div tag. It works find whether the **sample.jsp** is in **views** folder or inside **views/templates** folder.

Thank you all for your help.